# Core data with Restkit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I want to save the result in same order which is coming from server. I'm using Restkit with Coredata. I don't have added any constraint but it's saving in different order every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need add a key like `createAt` 
I remember you can keep data in order in CoreData

Also see this question: [iPhone: NSSet keep sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654286/iphone-nsset-keep-sort-order)